# Euphemisms for rejection (man-women and vice versa)

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests, euphemisms

Example:

> The more time passed, the more sure I became she’d [...] me.

The most common word in this case is *reject*. I'm wondering, though, what euphemisms I can use aside from *turn down*?

Comment: she'd **walked out on** me.

Comment: You have to be with someone before you can walk out on them. I read OP as thinking of the wooing-in-vain scenario.

Comment: She **dumped** me. Short and not very sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "*She **spurned** me*", though that's typically a very conscious, deliberate, and negative action.

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spurn), for example:

> ***spurn***: to reject (a person or thing) with contempt

So you would **not** be uncertain if the woman *spurned* you (she would make sure of that).

For a more passive rejection, one where she simply isn't reciprocating your affections, you can say "*My love went **unrequited***".

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unrequited?showCookiePolicy=true) again:

> ***unrequited***: (of love, affection, etc) not reciprocated or returned

Though you can see this phrase has the drawback about taking about your *love* as the object, rather than the woman or the relationship between the man and the woman.

Somewhere in the middle between passive and active rejection, in a way that talks about the relationship between the man and woman, is the construction:

> *The more time passed, the more sure I became she’d **dismissed** me.*

The drawback to *dismissed* is that it is not specific to love or affection (though your readers would understand that's what it meant in this context, i.e. the elided clause [*... as a lover*] would be inescapably implied).

In regards to your "vice-versa", I'll caution you that turning the question around, and not-requiting a *woman's* love, is, to put it mildly, *risky*:

> *Heaven has no rage like love to hatred turned, **Nor hell a fury like a woman [scorned⁵](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scorn)***
>
> <sub>aka *Hell hath no fury like a woman scorned*</sub>
>
> -- William Congreve's character *Zara*, in his play [The Mourning Bride](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U3ACAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=The%20mourning%20bride%23v=snippet&q=hatred&f=false) (Act III, Scene VIII).

Comment: These sound like what you'd hear in an 18th century novel.

Comment: Best I could do, @Robusto, best I could do ;)

Comment: Not exactly euphemisms though, are they?

Answer (score 4):

A number of indirect or figurative expressions for rejection exist, but I can't think of any single-word alternatives that aren't either just as brutal as "rejected" (for example, "dumped") or excessively vague ("released").

Here are some phrases that describe the process of rejection in indirect or metaphorical terms that may border on euphemism (I made up these examples; hence no attribution for what looks sort of like a block quote):

> The more time passed, the more sure I became that she was **giving me the cold shoulder**.
>
> The more time passed, the more sure I became that she’d decided to **try her luck** [or ***test the waters***] **elsewhere**.
>
> The more time passed, the more sure I became that she’d made up her mind to **put me in the rear-view mirror** [or ***put our relationship on permanent hold*** or ***move on***].

Comment: Somehow I accidentally voted this down. I can't fix it unless you edit your answer. Sorry.

Comment: @RichardKayser: Thanks for your note. I was away from my machine for several days, but have complied with your request for a useful edit so you can undo the downvote if you wish.

Comment: Will take care of it right now. Have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

> ...she'd **shown me the door**.

> ...she'd **flown the coop**.

> ...she'd **kicked me to the curb**.

Comment: These all seem quite good but can you expand and provide evidence, such as an online dictionary quotation? Take the [Tour] and see [answer] for more.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, ***disregard*** works irrespective of the man-woman and vice versa situation.

ODO:

> **[disregard](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disregard)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT] Pay no attention to; ignore:
>
> ‘Jamie disregarded Dougal with a shrug and pushed on the golden rod to
>   the door.’